# Unexpected value 'MDCTextField' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to add a Material Text Box to my Angular 7 app using the [docs here](https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/text-field/). Here are the relevant files:

## app.module.ts

```
...
import { MDCTextField } from "@material/textfield";
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, WordsComponent],
  imports: [
...
    MDCTextField
  ],
```

## words.component.html

```
...
<div class="mdc-text-field">
  <input type="text" id="my-text-field" class="mdc-text-field__input">
  <label class="mdc-floating-label" for="my-text-field">Hint text</label>
  <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
</div>
```

I also did npm install @material/textfield. I did not import/export anything into words.component.ts. Do I need to?

Answer (score 1):

Opp! Wrong docs. I should have been using the [Angular Material Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples) and as an example for a simple text box all I needed was this after importing material core:

## app.module.ts

```
import { MatInputModule } from "@angular/material/input";
```

## words.component.html

```
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>
```